# Angular 2 beginner. Typescript console.log a text with variable values

Tags: typescript

I am new to angular and cannot figure out how to log in console the value of 2 variables. As the result I get the undefined values of the variables. Why?

My html:

```
<form class="ui large form segment">
<h3 class="ui header">Add a link</h3>

<div class="field">
    <label for="title" #newtitle>Title</label>
    <input name="title">
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="link" #newlink>Link:</label>
    <input name="link">
</div>

<button (click)="addArticle(newtitle, newlink)" class="ui positive right floated button">
    Submit Link
</button>
```

.comonent.ts:

```
addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement): boolean{
    console.log(`Adding article title: ${title.value} and link: ${link.value}` );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ate you sure the elements have values?

Comment: I will update the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the template variables from the labels to the inputs themselves:

```
<form class="ui large form segment">
<h3 class="ui header">Add a link</h3>

<div class="field">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input #newtitle name="title">
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="link">Link:</label>
    <input #newlink name="link">
</div>

<button (click)="addArticle(newtitle, newlink)" class="ui positive right floated button">
    Submit Link
</button>
```